# Non-local Euler-Lagrange equations and Noether theorems

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, field-theory, noethers-theorem, non-locality

Following up my Noether theorem issues: how can Euler-Lagrange and Noether theorems be formulated for non-local lagrangians?

Two examples from the literature:

Example 1. Let $L(\phi, F(\phi))=-\dfrac{1}{2}\phi A(\square)\phi+\dfrac{1}{n+1}\phi^{n+1}$, where $A(\square)$ is a function on the D'Alembertian. Or  more generally, $L=-\dfrac{1}{2}\phi A(\square)\phi+kG(\phi)$, where $G$ is a non-local function on $\phi$ and its derivatives.

Example 2. Consider the GR extension given by $\mathcal{L}=kF(R)$, e.g., a common example from the literature, $F(R)=1/R$ or $F(R)=1/R^n$. What would be the corresponding Einstein Field Equations for these $F(R)$ theories?

I suppose it is complicated, but what do we need to derive EL for non-local lagrangians in general? And the Noether theorem? Having infinite derivatives that we do not know if they converge seems hard...I am not even sure if there is a whole analysis in the literature.

Comment: One of the Lagrangian agnostic definitions of "nonlocality" out there is that nonlocal theories are precisely those which violate Noether's theorem.

Comment: For a general action $S[\phi] = \int d^Dx L(\phi)$ you can derive the classical equations of motion by taking a single functional derivative $\delta S/\delta \phi(x) = 0$, using $\delta \phi(y)/\delta \phi(y) = \delta^D(y-x)$, and then letting derivatives act on the delta functions. Heuristically, one can then use the product rule to move the derivatives off the delta functions. Whether you can do that in closed form for $\int d^Dx \phi(x) A(\Box) \delta^D(y-x)$ will depend on what A is.